# How to handle the API response of the multipart request in java if reponse is a binary file?

Tags: java, image, httprequest, multipartform-data, httpresponse

I have converted the binary data(image/jpeg) in response to byte array and saved it in downloads folder. When executing the code run well without error and image got saved. But when I am opening the image file it displays loading meta data information failed.

My java files are here

Main class :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class sample_gui {

    private JPanel panelView;
    private JLabel sampleLabel;
    private JButton selectFolderButton;

    private List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

    public sample_gui() {

        selectFolderButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());
//                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
//                        "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
//                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                    File folder = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + folder.getName());
                    sampleLabel.setText(folder.getName());

                    listf(folder);
                    System.out.println(files);
                    maskAadhar(files.get(0));

                    /*try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get(folder))) {

                        List<String> result = walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                                .map(Path::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

                        result.forEach(System.out::println);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/

                    /*try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(folder))) {
                        paths
                                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                                .forEach(System.out::println);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/

                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void maskAadhar(File file){

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        File uploadFile1 = new File("/jarin/Downloads/images.jpeg");
        File uploadFile2 = new File("e:/Test/PIC2.JPG");
        String requestURL = "https://dev-kyd.tachyloans.com/api/v1/docanalysis/mask_aadhaar_num";

        try {

            MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(requestURL, charset);

            /*multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
            multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");*/

            multipart.addFormField("method", "mask_aadhar_num");
            multipart.addFormField("username", "orange_finance");
            multipart.addFormField("secret_key", "8leBG16ef3ec0575");
            multipart.addFormField("mask_length", "8");

            multipart.addFilePart("aadhaar_file", uploadFile1);

            byte[] response = multipart.finish();

            System.out.println(response.getClass().getName());

            System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

            /*for (String line : response) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }*/

            FileOutputStream outputStream;
            String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
            File maskedFile = new File(home+"/Downloads/" + "Aadhar_masked" + ".png");
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream (maskedFile, true);
            outputStream.write(response);
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public void listf(File folder) {
        files.clear();
        // Get all files from a directory.
        File[] fList = folder.listFiles();
        if(fList != null){
            for (File file : fList) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    files.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private  byte[] convertToBytes(List<String> list) {
       /* byte[][] data = new byte[strings.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            String string = strings[i];
            data[i] = string.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()); // you can chose charset
        }
        return data;*/

        int size = list.size();
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size ; ++i)
        {
            byteArray[i] = Byte.parseByte(list.get(i));
        }

        return byteArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Aadhar Masking");
        frame.setContentPane(new sample_gui().panelView);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Http multipart class

```
package sample.task;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MultipartUtility {


    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     * @param name field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();    
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     * @param name - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public byte[] finish() throws IOException {

        List<String> response = new ArrayList<>();

        byte[] bytes;

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //response.add(line);
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            bytes = buffer.toString().getBytes();
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Get this working in a command line app. The problem has nothing to do with Swing.

Comment: its a desktop app

Comment: So? How does Swing relate to the **stated problem?** Things relating to the  problem is what should be getting tagged, if it's possible to recreate this in a command line app, an applet or a servlet, it's safe to assume the problem is not related to any of them.

Comment: okay understand. Thanks